# How to match against list of maps in Karate?

Tags: karate

I have a list:

```
[{
  "a": 1
  "b": 2
}]
```

And I would like to match it this way:

```
And match response contains 
"""
[{
   "a": 1
}]
"""
```

However this does not work since the map inside of the list from the response has more keys. I just want to ignore them. Is there easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

```
* def response = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }]
* def expected = { a: 1 }
* match response contains '#(^expected)'
```

Or you could use `contains deep`:

```
* match response contains deep { a: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How can we add this validation if we have a map of string, any which is like below:

```
response map = {
 uniqueAddressId1: addressObject { 
  uniqueAddressId1,
  address data....
 },
 uniqueAddressId2: addressObject { 
  uniqueAddressId2,
  address data....
 }
}
```

Each addressId in map is associated to it's address object. And there's no way to know what addressId was generated